# Function on button click

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, reset

I'm in the middle of a tic tac toe game project I need to make a button in Javascript that will appear after the end of the round and which, when pressed, will start a new round.
I thought to make a function under click to remove a given class from the DOM. But I don't know how to do it. Can someone check and help?

I made an alert that is displayed after the end of the game but I need the game to reset

```
if (winCheck('playerOne', slots)) {
            gameTitle.innerHTML = 'You Won!'
            let btn = document.createElement('button')
            btn.innerHTML = 'Lets Play Again'
            btn.id = 'resetBtn'
            btn.onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById('resetBtn').remove()
            }
            document.body.appendChild(btn)
            return
        }
```

Comment: So where is your attempt to remove a class? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove

Comment: you can just google how to remove a class...

Comment: i edited post of my attemp of remove class. I did remove button but still cant remove player and computer moves and game result title.

Comment: You're removing an element in your updated code. Please read @epascarello's link to learn about removing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function you attribute to that button you could use the `document.getElementsByClassName`, store that value in a variable and iterate over the result removing the class from each element.

It would look something like this: [Replit - Programatic Global Class Removal](https://replit.com/@TarsiSurdi/Programatic-Global-Class-Removal#script.js)

I hope this does the trick for you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).